# Why do I keep getting The class method 'componentDidMount' must be makred either 'private' 'public' or 'protected' warnings, in my tsx files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am not sure what I am supposed to mark my methods in my react class components. I am getting this error on these methods: componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, componentWillUpdate and render

Here is a basic component that I have:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const { Component } = React;

export default class Loading extends Component<{}, {}>  {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('....something....');
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('....something....');
  }
  componentWillUpdate() {
    console.log('....something....');
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      background: '#f5f5f5',
      height: '100%',
      padding: '20px',
      textAlign: 'center',
      transition: 'all 0.5s linear',
      width: '100%'
    };
    return (
      <div id='app-loader' className='rounded' style={style}>
        <div className='loader large block rounded'>Loading...</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I can't put private render() etc because that breaks the component.

Comment: Just add `public` in front of the methods.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the tslint [member-access](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/member-access/) rule.

In *tslint.json*, change:

```
"member-access": true
```

To:

```
"member-access": [true, "no-public"] // Or false. Read the rule and see what you want.
```

Comment: I personally never have this set to only `true`. It's a waste of space and adds clutter to specify `public` when that's obvious from the absence of an access modifier.

Comment: There are also a few similar `Failed to compile` errors which are triggered by TSLint rules that are handy to know:

`"interface-name": [true, "never-prefix"]`: bypass the *interface name must start with a capitalized I* error, `"no-empty-interface": false`: allow to declare empty interfaces, `"ordered-imports": false`: don't check if classes are imported alphabetically