# Method React getDerivedStateFromProps problem when using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint

Use tslint.
We have the following code:

```
export default class TableCell extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps: IProps, prevState: IState) {
    return nextProps.status !== prevState.status ? {
      status: nextProps.status
    } : null;
  }

  constructor(props: any){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status: props.status
    };
  }

  ...
}
```

Which causes the following error:
**The class method 'getDerivedStateFromProps' must be marked either 'private', 'public', or 'protected'**

What is the problem?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945944/why-do-i-keep-getting-the-class-method-componentdidmount-must-be-makred-either

Comment: Please use the above solution linked by @arup-rakshit over mine as this allows you to globally mark default access as `public`, so would result in less code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I keep getting The class method 'componentDidMount' must be makred either 'private' 'public' or 'protected' warnings, in my tsx files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945944/why-do-i-keep-getting-the-class-method-componentdidmount-must-be-makred-either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO! Could you try marking the method as public explicitly?

```
export default class TableCell extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {
  public static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps: IProps, prevState: IState) {
    return nextProps.status !== prevState.status ? {
      status: nextProps.status
    } : null;
  }

  constructor(props: any){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status: props.status
    };
  }
}
```

This will let TS know it's OK for any code to invoke the static method from outside the class.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Please try marking the answer as accepted to help others identify it. Thanks!